# Get page source from active web session?

Tags: web-access

[`WebExecute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebExecute.html) allows to control a web browser through Mathematica. There are various actions one can perform programmatically through this function. However, I could not find the command to extract the website source text (the output you get by right-clicking on any website and selecting "View page source") with this function. Is it possible to obtain the page source of a website currently loaded by a web session in Mathematica 12.3? If so, which syntax can I use to do this?

As an example:

Let's say, we start a session and load a website:

```
session = StartWebSession[];
WebExecute["OpenPage" -> "https://www.wolfram.com"];
```

I would then like to get the page source, something like:

```
pageSource = GetPageSource[session];
```

Except, `GetPageSource` is not a real command. What should I write instead of `GetPageSource`?

Comment: maybe `Import[WebExecute[session, "PageURL"], "Source"]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes, that seems to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the *raw HTML source as a single string* using `Import` with `"Source"` as the second argument:

```
pageSource = Import[WebExecute[session, "PageURL"], "Source"]
```